# cordova + bootstrap: correct way to start a website a little lower

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

[image]

By default a app made with cordova starts at the left bottom corner:

I would prefer that it starts under the status bar on iOS.
I'm using cordova and bootstrap, what I do now is a `overrides.css` in the folder: `merges/ios/css`:

```
.app {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
```

This works, but I was wondering, is this a good way?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this. Your solution works fine. But if you would like to have some more control over the behavior and look of the status bar, you should try the Statusbar plugin for Cordova:

`$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar`

and then configure the statusbar look in the `config.xml` file:

```
<widget ...>
  ...
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Also checkout the cool status bar simulator app by Holly Schinsky: http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/